# simple implementation of line-delimited JSON objects (from lightweight command-line RDS decoder - redsea) to appropiate local database such as SQLite

Tags: json, database, sqlite

I am very new at this content. So I will try to explain us much as possible to understand my "problem". I think I have simple task, but I am confused and do not know where to even start. I am using 3rd-party plugin called 'redsea': (in ubuntu) https://github.com/windytan/redsea. She explains how does it work on her blog: http://www.windytan.com/2015/02/receiving-rds-with-rtl-sdr.html.

So my task is to dissect specific parsed-decoded strings (from that radio bitstream) and write to my local database (simultaneously if possible). And my problem is, that I do not have idea how to read that specific data and store it into convenient database.

From that point I would like to continue in a way to use multiply radio bitstreams (airband scan - with starting and ending point, with range and step) for some use-able simple statictics.

Please any kind of advice would help a lot, especially advice from where to even start for simple read and write into local database (I think that would be the 'Relational DBMS' - since I have not complex data to dissect, only long stream of simple name of song and artist - a best pick but I am not sure).

Thank you for your time,
Regards
AJ